# Design System that Supports React Components

Tags: gui, web, user-interface, react

I am currently researching design system framework's and have come across a few including, [Fractal](https://fractal.build/) and [Fabricator](http://fbrctr.github.io/). They seem like great tools, providing a user interface to view components, but from what I have seen so far you can only generate elements in HTML.

I am looking for a framework that will allow me to develop react components within the framework.

My goal is to have a shared resource between my design system framework and my react application.

Has anyone heard of a framework that supports react components, or knows of a work around to develop react components.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.